# SQLite returns inappropriate week number

Tags: sqlite, datetime, week-number

I am trying to get the [ISO week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) from the date in SQLite. When I try on few dates it gives the wrong week number.

For example:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%W', '2018-12-31')
```

returns 53.

However, there was a solution that suggested the usage of the following code:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', '2018-12-31 00:00:00') || '-' || ( (strftime('%j', date('2018-12-31 00:00:00', '-3 days', 'weekday 4')) - 1) / 7 + 1) as week
```

which returns `2018-1` but the expected result is `2019-1` because according to ISO week number* 2018-12-31 falls in 1st week of 2019.

What is the right way to get the correct ISO week number in SQLite ?

*Week number according to the ISO-8601 standard, weeks starting on Monday. The first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday (='First 4-day week')

Comment: What are you wanting the week number to be for the first one?

Comment: And of course your second one returns a string starting with 2018... the first `strftime()` ensures that. It'd be really broken if that snippet produced `'2019-1;`.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the reply, I want the output to be 2019-01 if the date is 2018-12-31.

Comment: You're going to have to explain your reasoning better in your question. How does a date in 2018 become one in 2019? And why do you go from week number to year + ? Day, month, week, what?

Comment: @Shawn sorry for the missing info, I am trying to get the ISO week number and 2018-12-31 happens to be the 1st week of 2019 according to ISO week standards. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution gave the year that I was expecting.

`select strftime('%Y', date('2018-12-31 00:00:00', '-3 days', 'weekday 4'))` returns 2019.

`strftime('%Y', date('2018-12-31 00:00:00', '-3 days', 'weekday 4')) || '-' || ( (strftime('%j', date(time, '-3 days', 'weekday 4')) - 1) / 7 + 1) as week`

returns the expected result, 2019-1.